# How to spyOn for a function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
var refresh = function(){
    console.info("refreshing page")
     window.location.reload();
}
```

I am supposed to spyOn the above function "window.location.reload()"

I have given the code as

```
describe('for  page refresh',function(){
    spyOn(window.location,'reload');    
it('should refresh the welcome page',function(){
        expect($location.reload),toHaveBeenCalled();
```

which is raising the error
        Error:  : reload is not declared writable or has no setter.

I am a newbie into angularJS. Any help would be much useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to jasmine. Check it out it may help you.

```js
describe('for  page refresh', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {

    refresh = {
      reload: function(value) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    };
    spyOn(refresh, 'reload');

  });

  it('should refresh the welcome page', function() {
    refresh.reload();
    expect(refresh.reload).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have a UserService with a method called Login and I would like to spy on that method then I would do:

```js
spyOn(UserService, 'login');
```

So if I wanted to check was it called then I would do:

```js
expect(UserService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I think this should give you a hint on what you're doing wrong.

Happy coding!